# How to retrieve open excel filename from remote pc using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, process, filenames, remote-access

Hi currently I'm having this code below.
It retrieves the filename of open excel document from process and displays it.

For now it can retrieve it from my own pc, but when I wanted to remotely retrieves it from other pc, it doesn't work.

I have authorized access and I could actually get the process id and name of remote pcs only.

```
Dim w As Object
        Dim processQ As String
        Dim processes As Object
        Dim processA As Object
        Dim pname As String
        w = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & pc & "\root\cimv2")
        processQ = "SELECT * FROM win32_process WHERE name = 'EXCEL.EXE'"
        processes = w.execquery(processQ)

        For Each processA In processes

            activeprocess = Process.GetProcessById(processA.processid)
            MsgBox(processA.processid & processA.name)
                Dim windows As IDictionary(Of IntPtr, String) = GetOpenWindowsFromPID(processA.processid)

            MsgBox(windows.Count())
                For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of IntPtr, String) In windows

                    Dim value As String = kvp.Value.ToString

                    If InStr(value, "Excel") = False Then
                        MsgBox(value)
                    End If
                Next
         Next
```

Can anyone tell me what should I do and what's wrong with this?

```
<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function GetShellWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, <Out()> ByRef lpdwProcessId As UInt32) As UInt32
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function IsWindowVisible(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Private Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean

<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function EnumWindows(ByVal enumFunc As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Private hShellWindow As IntPtr = GetShellWindow()
Private dictWindows As New Dictionary(Of IntPtr, String)
Private currentProcessID As Integer

Public Function GetOpenWindowsFromPID(ByVal processID As Integer) As IDictionary(Of IntPtr, String)
    dictWindows.Clear()
    currentProcessID = processID
    EnumWindows(AddressOf enumWindowsInternal, 0)
    Return dictWindows
End Function

Public Function enumWindowsInternal(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean
    If (hwnd <> hShellWindow) Then
        Dim windowPid As UInt32
        If Not IsWindowVisible(hwnd) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
        If (length = 0) Then
            Return True
        End If
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, windowPid)
        If (windowPid <> currentProcessID) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder(length)
        GetWindowText(hwnd, stringBuilder, (length + 1))
        dictWindows.Add(hwnd, stringBuilder.ToString)
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Sorry I'm quite new to vb.net.. but I'm learning thanks!